# How to emit from a custom Directive?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I've been working on custom directive (Scroller ) which detects the end of scroll. I want to emit a number as soon as the scroll end (i.e end of page is reached )

Custom Directive:

```
    import { HostListener , Directive, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';



@Directive({
    selector: '[scroller]'
})


export class scrollDirectiveComponent{
  @HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])

  @Output() emitPageNumber:EventEmitter<any> =new EventEmitter();
  pageNo:any=0;
  onScroll(event) {
    // do tracking
    console.log('scrolled', event.target.scrollTop);
    // Listen to click events in the component
    let tracker = event.target;

    let limit = tracker.scrollHeight - tracker.clientHeight;
    console.log(event.target.scrollTop, limit);
    if (event.target.scrollTop >= limit) {
      console.log('end reached');
      this.pageNo++;
      this.emitPageNumber.emit(this.pageNo);
    }
  }
}
```

I bound the directive to my parent  template

```
        <div class="alert-list" scroller (emitPageNumber)="fetchPageNumber($event)">
```

But when i scroll i get an error as
 core.umd.js:3462 EXCEPTION: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/menu-board/menu.component.html:63:8 caused by: self._scrollDirectiveComponent_32_3.emitPageNumber is not a function

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some code missing after the `@HostListener(...)`

```
@HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
scrollHandler(event) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the Reply . Now i understood what the error meant. my scroll handler was onScroll() and i had moved it below the @Output () .